# how to test interceptor of http errors in nestjs

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, interceptor

I have implemented this interceptor that transform http errors,

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class SolverInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
      intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        // next.handle() is an Observable of the controller's result value
        return next.handle()
        
          .pipe(catchError(error => {
    
            if (error.response.data.method_response.status === AppFrameworkStatus.USER_ERROR) {
           
                 const response: RawJobMethodResponse = error.response.data.method_response;
              throw new InvalidSolverDataException(response);
            } else {
              const response: RawJobMethodResponse = error.response.data.method_response;
    
             throw new InvalidSolverDataException(response);
            }
          }));
      }
    }
```

but i don't know how to test it correctly, i have tried testing like shown below but i am not sure about it , please help

```js
    it('it should call', async () => {
       
        callHandler.handle.mockResolvedValueOnce('next handle');
        const actualValue = interceptor.intercept({} as any, { handle: () => of(error) });
      actualValue.subscribe({
        next: (val) => {
          expect(val).toBeInstanceOf(InvalidSolverDataException)
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to test the CallHandler sending an error, first we have to  make it throw and error:

```
const handlerMock = {
  handle() {
    return throwError(() => new YourCustomError());
  },
} as CallHandler;
```

That is necessary because the we need the Observable to force your error to be caught by catchError function on pipe:

```
return next.handle().pipe(catchError((error) => doErrorHandling))
```

After then use the subscribe function on our interceptor return and with the [Observer interface](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observer) as the parameter instead of just the value to interact with the error:

```
next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
```

We can ignore next and complete since we are only interested in the error part and it should look similar to this:

```
it('Should throw InvalidSolverDataException when YourCustomError is thrown', (done) => {
  const ctxMock = {
    switchToHttp: () => ({
      getRequest: () => ({}),
    }),
  } as ExecutionContext;
  const handlerMock = {
    handle() {
      return throwError(() => new YourCustomError());
    },
  } as CallHandler;

  errorInterceptor.intercept(ctxMock, handlerMock).subscribe({
    error: (error) => {
      expect(error).toEqual(
        new InvalidSolverDataException('the text that should be here'),
      );
      done();
    },
  });
});
```

We added the done as a DoneCallback to the test function to avoid it being finished before our subscribe is resolved. By default it has a 5 seconds timeout but it can be customized: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous